# What is the cluster IP in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networking

I have created a cluster of three nodes: one master, two minions.
How to check the cluster IP in Kubernetes? 
Is it the IP of the master node?

Comment: What do you mean by the "cluster IP"? What is your use case?

Comment: Was trying to implement service type load-balancer from following link: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html ,there it asked for cluster-ip .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**ClusterIP** can mean 2 things: a type of service which is only accessible within a Kubernetes cluster, or the internal ("virtual") IP of components within a Kubernetes cluster. Assuming you're asking about finding the internal IP of a cluster, it can be accessed in 3 ways (using the [simple-nginx example](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/simple-nginx.html)):

1. Via command line `kubectl` utility:

   ```
   $ kubectl describe service my-nginx
   Name:           my-nginx
   Namespace:      default
   Labels:         run=my-nginx
   Selector:       run=my-nginx
   Type:           LoadBalancer
   IP:         10.123.253.27
   LoadBalancer Ingress:   104.197.129.240
   Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
   NodePort:       <unnamed>   30723/TCP
   Endpoints:      10.120.0.6:80
   Session Affinity:   None
   No events.
   ```
2. Via the kubernetes API (here I've used `kubectl proxy` to route through localhost to my cluster):

   ```
   $ kubectl proxy &
   $ curl -G http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/my-nginx
   {
     "kind": "Service",
     "apiVersion": "v1",
     "metadata": <omitted>,
     "spec": {
       "ports": [
         {
           "protocol": "TCP",
           "port": 80,
           "targetPort": 80,
           "nodePort": 30723
         }
       ],
       "selector": {
         "run": "my-nginx"
       },
       "clusterIP": "10.123.253.27",
       "type": "LoadBalancer",
       "sessionAffinity": "None"
     },
     "status": {
       "loadBalancer": {
         "ingress": [
           {
             "ip": "104.197.129.240"
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Via the `$<NAME>_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable within a Kubernetes container (in this example `my-nginx-yczg9` is the name of a pod in the cluster):

   ```
   $ kubectl exec my-nginx-yczg9 -- sh -c 'echo $MY_NGINX_SERVICE_HOST'
   10.123.253.27
   ```

More details on service IPs can be found in the [Services in Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html) documentation, and the previously mentioned [simple-nginx example](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/simple-nginx.html) is a good example of exposing a service outside your cluster with the `LoadBalancer` service type.

Comment: What are the service endpoints than? We get them by `kubectl get endpoints`?

Comment: @IvanAracki kubectl get endpoints gives you the pod IP not the service endpoints,

Comment: presumably the second link (now broken) should be updated to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 37):

Run this

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

It shows result like this where you can see the **Kubernetes master IP**

[image: Kubernetes Cluster IP]

Comment: This answer is one of my expectation. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Cluster IP is a virtual IP that is allocated by the K8s to a service. It is K8s internal IP.

A Cluster IP makes it accessible from any of the Kubernetes cluster’s nodes. The use of virtual IP addresses for this purpose makes it possible to have several pods expose the same port on the same node – All of these pods will be accessible via a unique IP address.

This IP is stable and never changes in the service lifecycle(unless deleted explicitly).

2 different pods can communicate using this IP, though I recommend using cluster DNS service.

Comment: Can we assign name to cluster IP without purchasing external dns name ? Could suggest you can we achieve this ?

Comment: I tried to ping & traceroute to cluster-ip from one of my pod in minikube, but neither of the commands are successful. 

I also tried doing "minikube ssh" and then ran ping & traceroute (after installing iputils-ping & traceroute packages), but no success either. 

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 8):

cluster IP only allocated to service, it is Kubernetes's internal ip。

Answer (score 0):

**The ClusterIP** *provides* a load-balanced IP address. One or more pods that match a label selector can forward traffic to the IP address. The ClusterIP service must define one or more ports to listen on with target ports to forward TCP/UDP traffic to containers.